# SQL Server : Linked Server row physical location

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I can query the physical location of a row in Microsoft SQL Server by %%physloc%% identifier. For example like this

```
select %%physloc%% from [testdb].[dbo].[table1_t4];
```

I have created a linked server of this SQL Server instance with dbserv instance. I can query the row of this instance like:

```
select * from [dbserv].[testdb].[dbo].[table1_t4];
```

But when I query the physical location of the rows

```
select %%physloc%% from [dbserv].[testdb].[dbo].[table1_t4];
```

This throws the error:

```
Invalid column name '%%'.
```

How do I workaround by obtaining the physical location of the row of the linked server for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked servers are all connected through [OLE DB Providers like ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx). While the ["Virtual Column %%phys_loc%%"](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-new-undocumented-physical-row-locator-function/) is an undocumented feature in SQL Server 2008. As such, OLE DB providers (barring the SQL Server native driver) aren't likely to support it, but I can't seem to find the documentation for it specifically.

Testing it out here, it also looks like it will only work when connected to the server locally, otherwise I get the same error you post here. Quoting the identifier throws an invalid column name error.

I don't believe you will be able to query this identifier through linked server at all.